# Laravel displaying different posts on a different pages

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Right now I display video on my page, once I click on it i get reddirected to /video{video}/view  (where {video} is video id).

```
@foreach($videos as $video)
            <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title video_name">{{ $video->video_name }}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe width="320" height="250" class="embed-responsive-item"
                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ $video->video_url  }}" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen" oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen">
                    </iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                    <p>Posted by {{ $video->user->first_name }} on {{ $video->created_at }}</p>
                        <hr class="postInfo">
                    </div>

                    <p>{{ $video->description }} </p>
                    <a href="{{ route('view.video', [$video->id]) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Continue to video</a>
                </div>
            </div>
         @endforeach
```

I have created posts in my database

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->text('body');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('video_id');
    });
```

But the problem is I don't know how can I display different posts on different videos, I'm getting user_id but I can't get video_id.

Post create function:

```
public function postCreatePost(Request $request) {
    $post = new Post();
    $post->body = $request['body'];
    $request->user()->posts()->save($post);
    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to give id to my routes where I'm posting, and then $post->video()->associate($video_id); with my videos id.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

Things you're going to create is called relationship and I'm assuming it's going to be one to one on video and post, then one to many on user and both for video and post.

I'm not sure how'd you get the user. But, the first thing to do is defining the foreign key.

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->text('body');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->integer('video_id');

    $table->foreign('user_id')
          ->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('video_id')
          ->references('id')->on('videos');
});
```

You're going to apply foreign keys also on the other tables. Anyways, I was assuming those two related tables are `users` and `videos`. Next, apply those relationship.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the post associated by the user.
     */
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Again, I was assuming that you're under `App` namespace. Then for the post.

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function video()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Video');
    }
}
```

Last, video.

```
class Video extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

I repeat my first assumption. *You're probably going to be have one to one on post and video, then one to many on user and post*. Which is mean, a user can has many posts, which the post will going to have a video.

Controller, if my assumption is correct at this point, it might look like similar to this.

```
//You might want to use route model binding instead
//@see https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding

public function showPost(Request $request, $post) {
    $post = \App\Post::where('id', $post)->with('video')->get();

    return view('template.post', ['post' => $post]);
}

public function showVideo(Request $request, $video) {
    $video = \App\Video::where('id', $video)->with('post')->get();

    return view('template.video', ['video' => $video]);
}

public function postCreatePost(Request $request)
{
   $post = new Post();
   $post->body = $request['body'];
   $request->user()->posts()->save($post);

   $video = new Video();
   $video->id = $request['video'];
   $post->video()->save($video);

   return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}
```